# CSS - Horizontal Scrolling Menu Not Scrolling

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a horizontal scrolling menu for mobile devices. I've taken advice from [this article](https://iamsteve.me/blog/entry/horizontal-scrolling-responsive-menu), stating this can be done with `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow-x: auto;`.

The result I'm trying to achieve: the content should get a horizontal scrollbar so the user can slide through the menu. The menu itself should go offscreen like so:

[image]

Here's what my code looks like:

```css
body {
     margin: 0;
     width: 500px; /* for this example */
}

.menubar {
     background:#000;
     height: 50px;
}

.logo {
     float:left;
     width: 25%;
     color:#fff;
     text-align: center;
}

.flat {
     margin:0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
}

.menu {
     width: 70%;
     float: right;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow-x: auto;
     -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
     -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}

.menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
     display: none;
}

.menu li {
     float: left;
     margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubar">
      <div class="logo">My Logo</div>
      <div class="menu">
            <ul class="flat menu">
                  <li><a href="">Menu item</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Menu item</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Menu item</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Menu item</a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why it is not working?

Comment: You don't explain what exactly isn't working or what article you're referencing.

Comment: @AlexanderRice My bad, forgot to add that. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove width from .menu class.
2. Add float: none; to .menu
3. Add display:inline; to .menu li

   ```
   body {
        margin: 0;
        width: 500px; /* for this example */
   }

   .menubar {
        background:#000;
        height: 60px;
   }

   .logo {
        float:left;
        width: 25%;
        color:#fff;
        text-align: center;
   }

   .flat {
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
   }

   .menu {
        float: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: auto;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
   }

   .menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
   }

   .menu li {
        margin-right: 1em;
     display:inline;

   }
   ```